# How do I test bootable USB created with UEFI GPT partition scheme

Tags: boot, usb, qemu, uefi, gpt

I am frequently testing bootable USB devices with different operating systems. Now I have to boot the whole computer just to test one USB device. How can I test the devices without booting? QEMU works sometimes, but not with UEFI GPT devices. Command `sudo qemu-system-x86_64  /dev/sde1` just hangs with "Booting from Hard Disk ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ovmf qemu-efi qemu
qemu-system-x86_64 --bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -m 4096 -enable-kvm -cdrom debian-9.2.1-amd64-DVD-1.iso -display sdl -vga virtio
```

You can specify also an HD (virtual or physical)

Answer (score 1):

You could try VirtualBox. VirtualBox supports UEFI (you will have to enable it in the settings.) VirtualBox also supports USB passtrough, so there may be a good chance you will be able to boot from the USB drive.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, no uefi support I guess http://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox

Comment: Neither did this. http://www.virten.net/2014/12/howto-usb-boot-a-vm-in-vmware-workstation-11/

Comment: VirtualBox does support EFI, I know because I have used it to boot Arch Linux with systemd-boot and an efistub kernel. You just have to enable EFI in Settings -> System -> Enable EFI (Special OSes only). (I don't know why it says that.) The real problem seems to be that VirtualBox does not allow booting from a USB drive. You could try trick mentioned last on the page you linked to, i.e. copy the contents of the USB drive to a disk file. That's not exaclty the same thing as booting from a real USB drive, though.

Comment: Yes, VirtualBox supports EFI, but Plop Boot Manager doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem to boot a Linux USB that I created from an iso. Turns out that I had to install manually the MBR code at the beginning of the device, with a procedure such as the one described on the Syslinux Wiki: [How to Create a Bootable USB - Step 3](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=HowTos#How_to_Create_a_Bootable_USB:_For_Linux)

Somehow the tools I used didn't do it automatically.